# Is $\lfloor\frac{\lfloor \frac{n}{s} \rfloor}{r}\rfloor = \lfloor \frac{n}{rs} \rfloor$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

where n,r,s are positive integers. It seems that this is true.

I know floors are not multiplicative. So $\lfloor \frac{a}{r} \rfloor \lfloor \frac{b}{s} \rfloor$ not necessarily equal to $ \lfloor \frac{ab}{rs} \rfloor$

Comment: Consider $n=s=1$ and $r=2$.  Is the expression on the left an integer?  Is the expression on the right?  Could they possibly be equal then?

Comment: However, $\left\lfloor \left\lfloor n/s \right\rfloor /r \right\rfloor = \left\lfloor n/\left(rs\right) \right\rfloor$ does hold. See Proposition 1.1.14 in [*18.781 (Spring 2016): Floor and arithmetic functions*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/floor.pdf).

Comment: Yes, I am considering integers. So expression on left and right are integers. So I should have put a floor on it. Let me edit.

Comment: @darij, thanks for the answer and the reference. Not sure why people downvote.. It is so hard to get points anyways :-)

Comment: "Not sure why people downvote"  Your original question was something which should have been *obviously* false and should have been disproven within at most two or three randomly selected examples.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks